# List<Class> in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I know java well but what i am not familiar with List of a Class. I can't really seem to find exact tutorial that would help me learn this. If there is any tutorial then please refer me or otherwise kindly tell me how to use `List<Class>`. For Example,

```
public class Students {
    int studentId;
    String studentName;
    int studentAge;
}
```

How to use

```
List<Students>
```

**Editted**

Just like Structures in c++, i want this Students to be a structure array to store data of multiple students. As in java there are no structures so i used class Students. If using List is not good for this purpose then kindly guide me.
Thanks!

Comment: What the heck do lists of classes have to do with the code you've posted? What do you want to use a list of classes to achieve?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking/don't understand. If it is `<Type>` part you should google for generics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: `List<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<MyType>();` And then use Google or s.th. to see what you can do with a `list`.

Comment: I want to use it just like we use structures in c++. Just to know how to use List of classes i gave this class as an example.

Comment: A list of class objects is no different to a list of string objects, I think you should reformulate the question to explain what your exact problem is.

Comment: *i am not familiar with List of a Class. I can't really seem to find exact tutorial that would help me learn this* check here: [Java: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: Another hint: if your class `Students` holds the data of one student, it would be better to name it just `Student` to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: I have editted the post is it not still helpfull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your naming conventions are off, it should be class Student not Students. And don't capitalize variable names. Anyway, List is a generic container interface and you can instantiate a concrete implementation of List and add Students to it.

```
List<Students> theStudents = new ArrayList<Students>();

Students aStudent = new Students();
aStudent.StudentId = 333;
aStudent.StudentName = "Help";

theStudents.add(aStudent);
```

Comment: This is what i wanted to ask. You really were a help :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Students> students = new ArrayList<Students>();
```